# how to create a utility method which has checked exception?

Tags: java, struts2, utilities

I have to set `private InputStream responseMsg` in my struts 2 application action class methods using following code

```
responseMsg = new ByteArrayInputStream(message.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

in this case i have to handle `UnsupportedEncodingException` checked exception. I want to assign `InputStream` in so many action methods if i added `throws UnsupportedEncodingException` in all methods means code looks messy. so i decided to create utility method in a Utility class

```
public class Utilities {

    public InputStream responseMessage(String message) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(message.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    }
}
```

invoked from my action class

```
responseMsg = new Utilities().responseMessage(message);
```

in this case also compile time error coming to handle `UnsupportedEncodingException` in action methods, help me to create Utility methods for all of my action class methods.

Comment: just handle the exception.... don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: What are you saving with the Utility method? It would still throw UnsupportedEncodingException, and the callers of that method would have to handle it or declare that they throw it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about `"UTF-8"` specifically, the recommended way is to throw an `Error` if something that must work by specification doesn’t. E.g.

```
public InputStream responseMessage(String message) {
  try {
    return new ByteArrayInputStream(message.getBytes("UTF-8"));
  } catch(UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
    throw new AssertionError("Every JVM must support UTF-8", ex);
  }
}
```

Since Java 7 live is much easier for this specific case:

```
public InputStream responseMessage(String message) {
  return new ByteArrayInputStream(message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
}
```

If it comes to arbitrary charsets, you should handle the possible exception, which is not a big deal as your code using the returned `InputStream` will have to deal with the declared `IOException`s anyway and `UnsupportedEncodingException` is a subclass of `IOException`. So the required `catch` or `throws` clause for `IOException` will cover `UnsupportedEncodingException` already.